# How to use a Java BigDecimal in Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker, bigdecimal

I get the BigDecimal value from a DB. It equals '0E-10'. When it is passed to a freemarker, the value is wrapped as 0.

I have already tried to swith on an arithmetic engine as a BigDecimal one, but it had no use.

Comment: Maybe a dump question, but what's the practical difference between 0E-10 and 0 (i.e., apart from the internal representation)? They are both equally zero, aren't they? Where should it make a difference for FreeMarker, what exactly is the problem with its output? Anyway, I'm fairly certain that the `ObjectWrapper` wraps the original `BigDecimals` as is, so if it was stored 0E-10 then it remains so. But probably the number formatter of Java just renders it as 0, which it is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to always print out in scientific notation?  You can use ${variable?string("0.##E0")} to do that in Freemarker.  Freemarker auto-converts things to user-friendly strings unless you tell it a specific format.

Answer (score -1):

follow this, http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_string_for_number